# Putting a password on a Xbox 360 game

Tags: xbox-360, world-of-tanks

My son love to play World of Tanks on his Xbox 360 but this is causing his grades to plummet. Is there a way I can put a password on the game so he can't play whenever he wants? Also, since this is an online game, can I put a password there too?

Comment: I don't own a 360 but I do know it has parental controls, please have a look in the [Xbox support site](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/security/xbox-live-parental-control) and see if the options provided there satisfy your need

Comment: Better method: Get a decent router where you can set allowed internet times for a certain LAN IP and fix the IP of the XBOX via static DHCP. This way he cannot play online at certain times.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness I'm not sure that's a better method at all; the parental controls provided by the Xbox are quite robust, and certainly much easier to turn on and off on demand than a scheduled IP block set up from a router.

Comment: In addition to the parental controls; if it is not already, move the the console to a more central location: Living room, den, kitchen. Somewhere with a TV that can be monitored. The parental controls are only as secure as the code you enter, and if left in an unsupervised location, I could totally see a younger me tirelessly trying to figure out what buttons you pressed in what order (Because if all that stood between me and my entertainment was a 4 button code, I'd take it as a challenge and [brute force it](http://youtu.be/Ujyj6QhRTao)).

Comment: @Trent Hawkins.  If I can remember correctly, there are at least 12 buttons you can use in your parental code.  With that, there is over 20K possible combinations that can be used.  Brute forcing would be long and tedious process that a somewhat attentive parent would notice.

Answer (score 7):

The best way and cheapest way is to set up family settings which has

Family Timer: This setting allows you to limit the time that your console can be used on a daily or weekly basis.

this will allow you to set the amount of time on his account without purchasing any extra utilities.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just take the Xbox away. So when he wants to play, he has to ask to play, which gives you the option of yes or no.